# Laravel funciona em "localhost" mas em servidor de produção não funciona

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, localhost

Estou com um problema em meu sistema de forma que ao publica-lo no Xamp em meu servidor, acessando localmente (neste mesmo servidor) todos os css e js são carregados corretamente, porem ao acessar de uma outra estação, nada é carregado (css, js, img). Já coloquei permissão em todos os diretórios da aplicação porem sem sucesso.

Para minhas tags de css fiz da seguinte forma:

Vejam o problema
[image: Css Carregou]

[image: Css nao carregou]

Comment: Coloca o link, ou os códigos..

Comment: Alteração da descrição do problema

Comment: Em produção o correto é você apontar um vhost para a pasta public do projeto